# When is it necessary to drain timer channel

Tags: go, timer

I have a loop that reads from a channel (indirectly receiving from a socket) but must also send a ping regularly if there is no other traffic. So I create a `time.Timer` on every loop iteration like this:

```
    var timer *time.Timer
    for {
        timer = time.NewTimer(pingFrequency)
        select {
        case message := <-ch:
            ....
        case <-timer.C:
            ping()
        }
        _ = timer.Stop()
    }
```

The doco for the `Stop` method implies you should drain the channel if it returns false but is that really necessary since the previous value of `timer` is no longer used and will be released by the GC.  Ie even if the old timer.C has an unread value it does not matter since nothing is using the channel any longer.

The doc. for `t.Stop()` says:

> To ensure the channel is empty after a call to Stop,
> check the return value and drain the channel.

My question is: Why would you need to ensure the channel is empty since nothing is using it and it will be freed by the GC?

Please note that I am aware of the proper way to stop a timer in the general case.

```
    if !timer.Stop() {
        select {
        case <-timer.C:
        default:
        }
    }
```

This specific question has not been answered on SO or elsewhere (apart from the comment from @JimB below).

Comment: The Timer’s channel is buffered, so there’s no reason to empty it if you are discarding it. If you’re not going to reuse the the Timer though, you should probably be using a Ticker instead.

Comment: Thanks @JimB, that's exactly what I thought.  I was just confused that the official doc says to drain the channel but I think that is for the case when you are going to reuse it.

BTW I thought of using a ticker but it has to be reset each time through the loop so I thought creating a new timer each time makes more sense. But maybe that creates extra load on the GC.  I guess I could use a ticker and simply send a ping at regular intervals irrespective of the other traffic.

Comment: If you do want the interval to reset after each loop, and you’re discarding the timer, just use `time.After`, which does exactly that already.

Comment: Thanks @JimB, another good point that I perhaps should have mentioned in my question.  Like `time.Ticker` I also considered `time.After` but since there may be a lot of these timers running at any one time using `time.Timer` allows me to stop it immediately. This will more quickly free go-routines and memory.
BTW I'll give you the points if the Q is reopened - maybe vote to reopen it?

Comment: It seems the question has been re-opened, so I posted an answer and also added a few real-world considerations.

Answer (score 0):

The timer will indeed be automatically freed by the GC after the timer fires and the goroutine has sent a message into the channel buffer. But this does mean that the goroutine will be taking up memory until the timer has fired.

This is sometimes OK, but if you have lots of these timers sitting around waiting to be GC'd, the memory usage can become significant. For example, if you're spawning timers in an HTTP request handler, you could wind up in a situation where the timers aren't finishing fast enough relative to the rate at which you're serving requests, and the server will eventually run out of memory and crash.

If you're writing library code, it's especially important to manually clean up any timers that you create, because you don't know how people are going to use your library and whether the memory usage will be a significant problem for them.